# SFMC: Advance a contact manually in the journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

I have a custom activity in the journey builder. I am doing a third party API call.

The third party api call needs to send contact infos in batches. For that i have a queue that collects the data from the /execute route of the custom activity.

However now i loose control over stopping a contact in the journey in case the 3rd party api call has failed.

I was thinking to hard error by default all the contacts in the /execute route and then via another API call to SFMC resume them only after the 3rd party API call has succeeded.

Is there such thing to manually control the flow of the contacts (even hard errored ones) without using API-Events of SFMC? I dont want the user to create an api event.

Comment: have you looked at the wait until activities?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to manually advance contact in the Journey.

Comment: Can you add more details for your answer? This will help the OP understand better.